# Yii2 dropdown list : add html markups like data-food="..." to my options

Tags: php, html, yii2

I'm building an app using Yii2.  I am generating dropdown lists using the Html Helper provided by Yii2 :

```
<?= Html::dropDownList('food', $food_id, $foodList, ['id'=>'food-select']); ?>
```

where $food_id is the default selected option and $foodList is an array containing key-value pairs that represent the options value and text.

It works well, but I'd need to add a html-markup (data-food="...") to my options.  Something like this:

```
<select id='food-select'>
    <option id="1" data-food="apple-info">Apple</option>
</select>
```

Is this possible using the Html::dropDownList() method?  Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `options` parameter of the `$options` array as below:

```
$food_list = [1 => 'Apple', 2 => 'Banana', 4 => 'Orange']; //let's assume

<?= Html::dropDownList('food', $food_id, $food_list, [
    'id'=>'food-select',
    'options' => [
        1 => ['data-food'=>'apple-info'], //index must be same as the option value
        2 => ['data-food'=>'banana-info'],
        4 => ['data-food'=>'orange-info']
    ]
]); 
?>
```

Outputs following drop-down -

```
<select id="food-select" name="food">
    <option value="1" data-food="apple-info">Apple</option>
    <option value="2" data-food="banana-info">Banana</option>
    <option value="4" data-food="orange-info">Orange</option>
</select>
```

From the documentation - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#dropDownList()-detail

> options: array, the attributes for the select option tags. The array
>   keys must be valid option values, and the array values are the extra
>   attributes for the corresponding option tags.